# How can I revert a config file back to the originally installed version after I have edited it?

Tags: configuration, apt

I want to revert a file in `/etc/` back to its originally-installed form. I have edited the file since it was installed. How can I revert this config file? Apt is smart enough *not* to overwrite edited config files, so how do I tell it that I *want* it to do so?

For argument's sake, let's say that I want to revert the file `/etc/foo.conf` from the package `foo`.

Comment: For all those who suggest purging and reinstalling `foo`, what if `bar` depends on `foo` and I don't want to remove `bar`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181179/61218) provided by Ryan Thomson was heading to the right way. Still it would not be able to do the job (The details reason is given below).

The correct (and easiest) way of doing so is using `-o` with `apt` to pass dpkg option and force `dpkg` to ask you whether you want to retain the modified config files or the original ones. The command will be like this -

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install foo
```

This would ask you a question like

```
Configuration file '/etc/foo/foo.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
     Version in package is the same as at last installation.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** foo.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

You have to press either **Y** or **I** to install package maintainer's original config file. You can even press D to see what the changes or start a root shell with Z option to fix yourself.

**Note:** After the replacement, you'll find your modified file as `at /etc/foo/foo.conf.dpkg-old`

---

### Why other options would not work?

Because the other options in dpkg doesn't work well. The options which deals with a package's config files are

- `--force-confmiss`
- `--force-confnew`
- `--force-confold`
- `--force-confdef`

**`--force-confmiss`** would not work when package version doesn't change. From man-page

> > If a conffile has been modified and the version in  the package  did  change,  always  install  the  new version without prompting, unless the  **--force-confdef** is  also  specified,  in which case the default action is preferred.

**`--force-confmiss`** works with missing conffiles. It too will fail when version didn't change. Quoting [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> > confmiss: If  a  conffile  is  missing  and  the version in the package did change, always install the missing conffile  without prompting.  This  is  dangerous, since it means not preserving a change (removing) made to the file

**`--force-confold`** will retain modified version only if *the version is changed*. For same package, it too will fail. Quoting [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> > confold: If a conffile has been modified and the version in the package  did  change, always  keep  the  old  version   without prompting,  unless  the  **--force-confdef**  is  also specified, in which case the default action is preferred.

**`--force-confdef`** will also fail because the default action is to retain older file (Indicated from the message shown with `--force-confask`. It has line `(Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N]` which means retaining is default. See above). And if `--force-confnew` is specified but version do not change, that too will not work. Quoting [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> > confdef:  If a conffile has been modified and the version in the package did  change, always choose the default action without prompting. If there is no default action it will stop to ask the user  unless  **--force-confnew**  or  **--force-confold**  is also been given, in which case it  will  use  that  to  decide  the  final action.

Only **`--force-confask`** will work, because it will explicitly ask you the question even when the version is same. Quoting [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> > confask: If a conffile has been modified always offer to replace it with the version in the package, even if the version in the package did  not  change  (since  dpkg  1.15.8). If  any  of **--force-confmiss**, **--force-confnew**, **--force-confold**, or **--force-confdef**  is also given, it will be used to decide the final action.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Your answer was very comprehensive, thanks.  Is it also possible to automatically answer the question with "y", i. e. effectively `--force-confnew`?  I tried `apt-get […] -y`, but that didn't work.  (If it is not possible, please also edit the answer to say so.)

Comment: @TimLandscheidt you're asking if it's possible to use `--force-confnew` without asking? I think that is the default case, which means it will retain your changes. `--force-confask` makes `apt` always ask the question, otherwise, you'd use other options if you already know the answer.

Comment: Ha, I had tried `-o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew` unsuccessfully (as your answer predicted) and did not read the error message when I tried `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask --force-confnew"`.  However, `apt-get --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confask -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew install $package` correctly overwrote the change configuration files of `$package`.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me with a blank sshd_config. It's not detected as a change. I assume this has something to do with the setup script using ucf

Answer (score 12):

If the harm is already done, here's a command line way of getting back the official version of the configuration file. First, download the package file (either with `apt-get --download-only` as below, or from the package page on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)), then extract its contents in a temporary location. You can then copy the file into `/etc`. Make sure to respect the original permissions (most files in `/etc` are owned by root and mode 644 (i.e. word-readable and root-writable), but each exception is there for an important reason).

```
sudo apt-get --download-only --reinstall install foo
mkdir /tmp/foo
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/foo_VERSION_ARCH.deb /tmp/foo
```

Note that this doesn't apply to the configuration files that are not from a package, such as `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/passwd`. If you lose these, you're on your own. (Most are very system-dependent anyway.)

---

For the future, I recommend using [**etckeeper**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/etckeeper) [image: Install etckeeper]. Install the package and run `sudo etckeeper init`. This sets up version control for all files in `/etc`. You don't need to do anything else to manage etckeeper; you only need to interact with it when you want to do a version control operation, such as referring to older files. Files are automatically committed before and after each run of apt and every night (this is configurable).

By default, on Ubuntu, etckeeper uses [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/). Change the setting in `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` before running `etckeeper init` if you prefer Darcs, Git or Mercury.

With Bazaar, to revert `/etc/foo.conf` to the last committed version:

```
cd /etc
sudo bzr revert foo.conf
```

If you want to go back further in time, use `sudo bzr log foo.conf` to view the history of the file, and `sudo bzr revert -r 42 foo.conf` if you've determined that `revno: 42` is the revision you want to revert to.

Answer (score 7):

You could download the package manually from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), extract the file and replace your version with it.

Or you could:

```
sudo rm /etc/foo.conf # just for good measure
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install foo
```

The second feels a lot more brutish. It might wipe other config out too if it uses more than one file. The first is more clicking and effort but it seems much safer.

For the second, you might be able to just delete the file and --reinstall might replace it. If so, that would be safer.

Comment: No, deleting a configuration file is considered a valid modification, and is preserved by apt.

Comment: Is it possible to purge and reinstall a package if other installed packages depend on it?

Comment: @RyanThompson Yeah, `apt-get --reinstall purge package` won't hurt dependants.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the package, you may find a default config file in `/usr/share/doc/foo/examples`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic (Ubuntu tweak is even more convenient but synaptic is more straight forward) and choose "completely remove package". This will delete all config files  (you might want to backup these files!).

Then reinstall. You're done.

With Ubuntu Tweak you get even more options for cleanup, rerolling and configuration backups. Maybe you want to give it a look. It's in the softwarecenter.

p.s.: Synaptic also uses the "purge" option (like mentioned by Oli above ...) 
- just with a GUI for more comfortable handling.

Comment: What package removes files in your home directory when you remove it? I would consider this a grave bug!

Comment: @Gilles: You're right. The personal settings within your home directory won't be touched by purge. I edited and corrected the above. sry

Comment: Purging the package may not be an option if others depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer that I vaguely remembered from years ago:

```
dpkg --force-confnew --force-confmiss -i PACKAGE.deb
```

The "confnew" argument forces dpkg to replace modified config files with the package-provided ones, and the "confmiss" does likewise with config files that have been deleted.

According to [this chatlog](http://ircarchive.info/debian/2007/4/8/110.html), you can also use these options through apt-get in the following manner:

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confnew --force-confmiss" --reinstall install PACKAGE
```

which saves you from needing to find the deb file yourself.

Obviously, these options are dangerous and have the potential to blow away important system configuration files if misused.

Comment: The problem with `--force-confnew` is it will only install new config files if the version is change. If you're reinstalling same version, it will not install new config file as I have tested it explicitly

Comment: And `--force-confmiss` will only install new config file if version is changed and config is missing. As described in the man page `confmiss: If a conffile is missing and the version in the package did change, always install the missing conffile without prompting.
              This is dangerous, since it means not preserving a change (removing) made to the file.`