# How to restore /etc/services?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery

Using tee without the `--append` flag, I just managed to clear out my `/etc/services` file.

1. Can someone send me their copy from Maverick?
2. How to recover from silly mistakes like this on the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd agree with Jorge but I can't say which package `/etc/services` comes from. It certainly doesn't seem like one that would be healthy to reinstall although I could be wrong.

Edit: `/etc/services` comes from the `netbase` package and gets customised by other services that install. You can find that out by running `dlocate /etc/services` (you need to install `dlocate` first).

So following [my answer on the other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12699/how-can-i-revert-a-config-file-back-to-the-originally-installed-version-after-i-h/12700#12700), you could download [the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/netbase) manually and extract the file. Or "risk" it with `sudo apt-get --reinstall --purge install netbase`. I say risk only because the first method is just a lot safer.

For the sake of not making things worse, here's a services file from an "almost virgin" upgrade to Maverick:

```
# Network services, Internet style
#
# Note that it is presently the policy of IANA to assign a single well-known
# port number for both TCP and UDP; hence, officially ports have two entries
# even if the protocol doesn't support UDP operations.
#
# Updated from http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers and other
# sources like http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/etc/services .
# New ports will be added on request if they have been officially assigned
# by IANA and used in the real-world or are needed by a debian package.
# If you need a huge list of used numbers please install the nmap package.

tcpmux      1/tcp               # TCP port service multiplexer
echo        7/tcp
echo        7/udp
discard     9/tcp       sink null
discard     9/udp       sink null
systat      11/tcp      users
daytime     13/tcp
daytime     13/udp
netstat     15/tcp
qotd        17/tcp      quote
msp     18/tcp              # message send protocol
msp     18/udp
chargen     19/tcp      ttytst source
chargen     19/udp      ttytst source
ftp-data    20/tcp
ftp     21/tcp
fsp     21/udp      fspd
ssh     22/tcp              # SSH Remote Login Protocol
ssh     22/udp
telnet      23/tcp
smtp        25/tcp      mail
time        37/tcp      timserver
time        37/udp      timserver
rlp     39/udp      resource    # resource location
nameserver  42/tcp      name        # IEN 116
whois       43/tcp      nicname
tacacs      49/tcp              # Login Host Protocol (TACACS)
tacacs      49/udp
re-mail-ck  50/tcp              # Remote Mail Checking Protocol
re-mail-ck  50/udp
domain      53/tcp              # name-domain server
domain      53/udp
mtp     57/tcp              # deprecated
tacacs-ds   65/tcp              # TACACS-Database Service
tacacs-ds   65/udp
bootps      67/tcp              # BOOTP server
bootps      67/udp
bootpc      68/tcp              # BOOTP client
bootpc      68/udp
tftp        69/udp
gopher      70/tcp              # Internet Gopher
gopher      70/udp
rje     77/tcp      netrjs
finger      79/tcp
www     80/tcp      http        # WorldWideWeb HTTP
www     80/udp              # HyperText Transfer Protocol
link        87/tcp      ttylink
kerberos    88/tcp      kerberos5 krb5 kerberos-sec # Kerberos v5
kerberos    88/udp      kerberos5 krb5 kerberos-sec # Kerberos v5
supdup      95/tcp
hostnames   101/tcp     hostname    # usually from sri-nic
iso-tsap    102/tcp     tsap        # part of ISODE
acr-nema    104/tcp     dicom       # Digital Imag. & Comm. 300
acr-nema    104/udp     dicom       # Digital Imag. & Comm. 300
csnet-ns    105/tcp     cso-ns      # also used by CSO name server
csnet-ns    105/udp     cso-ns
rtelnet     107/tcp             # Remote Telnet
rtelnet     107/udp
pop2        109/tcp     postoffice pop-2 # POP version 2
pop2        109/udp     pop-2
pop3        110/tcp     pop-3       # POP version 3
pop3        110/udp     pop-3
sunrpc      111/tcp     portmapper  # RPC 4.0 portmapper
sunrpc      111/udp     portmapper
auth        113/tcp     authentication tap ident
sftp        115/tcp
uucp-path   117/tcp
nntp        119/tcp     readnews untp   # USENET News Transfer Protocol
ntp     123/tcp
ntp     123/udp             # Network Time Protocol
pwdgen      129/tcp             # PWDGEN service
pwdgen      129/udp             # PWDGEN service
loc-srv     135/tcp     epmap       # Location Service
loc-srv     135/udp     epmap
netbios-ns  137/tcp             # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns  137/udp
netbios-dgm 138/tcp             # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-dgm 138/udp
netbios-ssn 139/tcp             # NETBIOS session service
netbios-ssn 139/udp
imap2       143/tcp     imap        # Interim Mail Access P 2 and 4
imap2       143/udp     imap
snmp        161/tcp             # Simple Net Mgmt Protocol
snmp        161/udp             # Simple Net Mgmt Protocol
snmp-trap   162/tcp     snmptrap    # Traps for SNMP
snmp-trap   162/udp     snmptrap    # Traps for SNMP
cmip-man    163/tcp             # ISO mgmt over IP (CMOT)
cmip-man    163/udp
cmip-agent  164/tcp
cmip-agent  164/udp
mailq       174/tcp         # Mailer transport queue for Zmailer
mailq       174/udp         # Mailer transport queue for Zmailer
xdmcp       177/tcp             # X Display Mgr. Control Proto
xdmcp       177/udp
nextstep    178/tcp     NeXTStep NextStep   # NeXTStep window
nextstep    178/udp     NeXTStep NextStep   #  server
bgp     179/tcp             # Border Gateway Protocol
bgp     179/udp
prospero    191/tcp             # Cliff Neuman's Prospero
prospero    191/udp
irc     194/tcp             # Internet Relay Chat
irc     194/udp
smux        199/tcp             # SNMP Unix Multiplexer
smux        199/udp
at-rtmp     201/tcp             # AppleTalk routing
at-rtmp     201/udp
at-nbp      202/tcp             # AppleTalk name binding
at-nbp      202/udp
at-echo     204/tcp             # AppleTalk echo
at-echo     204/udp
at-zis      206/tcp             # AppleTalk zone information
at-zis      206/udp
qmtp        209/tcp             # Quick Mail Transfer Protocol
qmtp        209/udp             # Quick Mail Transfer Protocol
z3950       210/tcp     wais        # NISO Z39.50 database
z3950       210/udp     wais
ipx     213/tcp             # IPX
ipx     213/udp
imap3       220/tcp             # Interactive Mail Access
imap3       220/udp             # Protocol v3
pawserv     345/tcp             # Perf Analysis Workbench
pawserv     345/udp
zserv       346/tcp             # Zebra server
zserv       346/udp
fatserv     347/tcp             # Fatmen Server
fatserv     347/udp
rpc2portmap 369/tcp
rpc2portmap 369/udp             # Coda portmapper
codaauth2   370/tcp
codaauth2   370/udp             # Coda authentication server
clearcase   371/tcp     Clearcase
clearcase   371/udp     Clearcase
ulistserv   372/tcp             # UNIX Listserv
ulistserv   372/udp
ldap        389/tcp         # Lightweight Directory Access Protocol
ldap        389/udp
imsp        406/tcp         # Interactive Mail Support Protocol
imsp        406/udp
https       443/tcp             # http protocol over TLS/SSL
https       443/udp
snpp        444/tcp             # Simple Network Paging Protocol
snpp        444/udp
microsoft-ds    445/tcp             # Microsoft Naked CIFS
microsoft-ds    445/udp
kpasswd     464/tcp
kpasswd     464/udp
saft        487/tcp         # Simple Asynchronous File Transfer
saft        487/udp
isakmp      500/tcp         # IPsec - Internet Security Association
isakmp      500/udp         #  and Key Management Protocol
rtsp        554/tcp         # Real Time Stream Control Protocol
rtsp        554/udp         # Real Time Stream Control Protocol
nqs     607/tcp             # Network Queuing system
nqs     607/udp
npmp-local  610/tcp     dqs313_qmaster      # npmp-local / DQS
npmp-local  610/udp     dqs313_qmaster
npmp-gui    611/tcp     dqs313_execd        # npmp-gui / DQS
npmp-gui    611/udp     dqs313_execd
hmmp-ind    612/tcp     dqs313_intercell    # HMMP Indication / DQS
hmmp-ind    612/udp     dqs313_intercell
qmqp        628/tcp
qmqp        628/udp
ipp     631/tcp             # Internet Printing Protocol
ipp     631/udp
#
# UNIX specific services
#
exec        512/tcp
biff        512/udp     comsat
login       513/tcp
who     513/udp     whod
shell       514/tcp     cmd     # no passwords used
syslog      514/udp
printer     515/tcp     spooler     # line printer spooler
talk        517/udp
ntalk       518/udp
route       520/udp     router routed   # RIP
timed       525/udp     timeserver
tempo       526/tcp     newdate
courier     530/tcp     rpc
conference  531/tcp     chat
netnews     532/tcp     readnews
netwall     533/udp             # for emergency broadcasts
gdomap      538/tcp             # GNUstep distributed objects
gdomap      538/udp
uucp        540/tcp     uucpd       # uucp daemon
klogin      543/tcp             # Kerberized `rlogin' (v5)
kshell      544/tcp     krcmd       # Kerberized `rsh' (v5)
afpovertcp  548/tcp             # AFP over TCP
afpovertcp  548/udp
remotefs    556/tcp     rfs_server rfs  # Brunhoff remote filesystem
nntps       563/tcp     snntp       # NNTP over SSL
nntps       563/udp     snntp
submission  587/tcp             # Submission [RFC4409]
submission  587/udp
ldaps       636/tcp             # LDAP over SSL
ldaps       636/udp
tinc        655/tcp             # tinc control port
tinc        655/udp
silc        706/tcp
silc        706/udp
kerberos-adm    749/tcp             # Kerberos `kadmin' (v5)
#
webster     765/tcp             # Network dictionary
webster     765/udp
rsync       873/tcp
rsync       873/udp
ftps-data   989/tcp             # FTP over SSL (data)
ftps        990/tcp
telnets     992/tcp             # Telnet over SSL
telnets     992/udp
imaps       993/tcp             # IMAP over SSL
imaps       993/udp
ircs        994/tcp             # IRC over SSL
ircs        994/udp
pop3s       995/tcp             # POP-3 over SSL
pop3s       995/udp
#
# From ``Assigned Numbers'':
#
#> The Registered Ports are not controlled by the IANA and on most systems
#> can be used by ordinary user processes or programs executed by ordinary
#> users.
#
#> Ports are used in the TCP [45,106] to name the ends of logical
#> connections which carry long term conversations.  For the purpose of
#> providing services to unknown callers, a service contact port is
#> defined.  This list specifies the port used by the server process as its
#> contact port.  While the IANA can not control uses of these ports it
#> does register or list uses of these ports as a convienence to the
#> community.
#
socks       1080/tcp            # socks proxy server
socks       1080/udp
proofd      1093/tcp
proofd      1093/udp
rootd       1094/tcp
rootd       1094/udp
openvpn     1194/tcp
openvpn     1194/udp
rmiregistry 1099/tcp            # Java RMI Registry
rmiregistry 1099/udp
kazaa       1214/tcp
kazaa       1214/udp
nessus      1241/tcp            # Nessus vulnerability
nessus      1241/udp            #  assessment scanner
lotusnote   1352/tcp    lotusnotes  # Lotus Note
lotusnote   1352/udp    lotusnotes
ms-sql-s    1433/tcp            # Microsoft SQL Server
ms-sql-s    1433/udp
ms-sql-m    1434/tcp            # Microsoft SQL Monitor
ms-sql-m    1434/udp
ingreslock  1524/tcp
ingreslock  1524/udp
prospero-np 1525/tcp            # Prospero non-privileged
prospero-np 1525/udp
datametrics 1645/tcp    old-radius
datametrics 1645/udp    old-radius
sa-msg-port 1646/tcp    old-radacct
sa-msg-port 1646/udp    old-radacct
kermit      1649/tcp
kermit      1649/udp
l2f     1701/tcp    l2tp
l2f     1701/udp    l2tp
radius      1812/tcp
radius      1812/udp
radius-acct 1813/tcp    radacct     # Radius Accounting
radius-acct 1813/udp    radacct
msnp        1863/tcp            # MSN Messenger
msnp        1863/udp
unix-status 1957/tcp            # remstats unix-status server
log-server  1958/tcp            # remstats log server
remoteping  1959/tcp            # remstats remoteping server
cisco-sccp  2000/tcp    sieve       # Cisco SCCP
cisco-sccp  2000/udp
search      2010/tcp    ndtp
pipe_server 2010/tcp
nfs     2049/tcp            # Network File System
nfs     2049/udp            # Network File System
gnunet      2086/tcp
gnunet      2086/udp
rtcm-sc104  2101/tcp            # RTCM SC-104 IANA 1/29/99
rtcm-sc104  2101/udp
gsigatekeeper   2119/tcp
gsigatekeeper   2119/udp
gris        2135/tcp        # Grid Resource Information Server
gris        2135/udp        # Grid Resource Information Server
cvspserver  2401/tcp            # CVS client/server operations
cvspserver  2401/udp
venus       2430/tcp            # codacon port
venus       2430/udp            # Venus callback/wbc interface
venus-se    2431/tcp            # tcp side effects
venus-se    2431/udp            # udp sftp side effect
codasrv     2432/tcp            # not used
codasrv     2432/udp            # server port
codasrv-se  2433/tcp            # tcp side effects
codasrv-se  2433/udp            # udp sftp side effect
mon     2583/tcp            # MON traps
mon     2583/udp
dict        2628/tcp            # Dictionary server
dict        2628/udp
gsiftp      2811/tcp
gsiftp      2811/udp
gpsd        2947/tcp
gpsd        2947/udp
gds_db      3050/tcp            # InterBase server
gds_db      3050/udp
icpv2       3130/tcp    icp     # Internet Cache Protocol
icpv2       3130/udp    icp
mysql       3306/tcp
mysql       3306/udp
nut     3493/tcp            # Network UPS Tools
nut     3493/udp
distcc      3632/tcp            # distributed compiler
distcc      3632/udp
daap        3689/tcp            # Digital Audio Access Protocol
daap        3689/udp
svn     3690/tcp    subversion  # Subversion protocol
svn     3690/udp    subversion
suucp       4031/tcp            # UUCP over SSL
suucp       4031/udp            # UUCP over SSL
sysrqd      4094/tcp            # sysrq daemon
sysrqd      4094/udp            # sysrq daemon
remctl      4373/tcp        # Remote Authenticated Command Service
remctl      4373/udp        # Remote Authenticated Command Service
iax     4569/tcp            # Inter-Asterisk eXchange
iax     4569/udp
radmin-port 4899/tcp            # RAdmin Port
radmin-port 4899/udp
rfe     5002/udp            # Radio Free Ethernet
rfe     5002/tcp
mmcc        5050/tcp    # multimedia conference control tool (Yahoo IM)
mmcc        5050/udp
sip     5060/tcp            # Session Initiation Protocol
sip     5060/udp
sip-tls     5061/tcp
sip-tls     5061/udp
aol     5190/tcp            # AIM
aol     5190/udp
xmpp-client 5222/tcp    jabber-client   # Jabber Client Connection
xmpp-client 5222/udp    jabber-client
xmpp-server 5269/tcp    jabber-server   # Jabber Server Connection
xmpp-server 5269/udp    jabber-server
cfengine    5308/tcp
cfengine    5308/udp
mdns        5353/tcp            # Multicast DNS
mdns        5353/udp            # Multicast DNS
postgresql  5432/tcp    postgres    # PostgreSQL Database
postgresql  5432/udp    postgres
freeciv     5556/tcp    rptp        # Freeciv gameplay
freeciv     5556/udp
amqp        5672/tcp
amqp        5672/udp
amqp        5672/sctp
ggz     5688/tcp            # GGZ Gaming Zone
ggz     5688/udp            # GGZ Gaming Zone
x11     6000/tcp    x11-0       # X Window System
x11     6000/udp    x11-0
x11-1       6001/tcp
x11-1       6001/udp
x11-2       6002/tcp
x11-2       6002/udp
x11-3       6003/tcp
x11-3       6003/udp
x11-4       6004/tcp
x11-4       6004/udp
x11-5       6005/tcp
x11-5       6005/udp
x11-6       6006/tcp
x11-6       6006/udp
x11-7       6007/tcp
x11-7       6007/udp
gnutella-svc    6346/tcp            # gnutella
gnutella-svc    6346/udp
gnutella-rtr    6347/tcp            # gnutella
gnutella-rtr    6347/udp
sge_qmaster 6444/tcp            # Grid Engine Qmaster Service
sge_qmaster 6444/udp            # Grid Engine Qmaster Service
sge_execd   6445/tcp            # Grid Engine Execution Service
sge_execd   6445/udp            # Grid Engine Execution Service
afs3-fileserver 7000/tcp    bbs     # file server itself
afs3-fileserver 7000/udp    bbs
afs3-callback   7001/tcp            # callbacks to cache managers
afs3-callback   7001/udp
afs3-prserver   7002/tcp            # users & groups database
afs3-prserver   7002/udp
afs3-vlserver   7003/tcp            # volume location database
afs3-vlserver   7003/udp
afs3-kaserver   7004/tcp            # AFS/Kerberos authentication
afs3-kaserver   7004/udp
afs3-volser 7005/tcp            # volume managment server
afs3-volser 7005/udp
afs3-errors 7006/tcp            # error interpretation service
afs3-errors 7006/udp
afs3-bos    7007/tcp            # basic overseer process
afs3-bos    7007/udp
afs3-update 7008/tcp            # server-to-server updater
afs3-update 7008/udp
afs3-rmtsys 7009/tcp            # remote cache manager service
afs3-rmtsys 7009/udp
font-service    7100/tcp    xfs     # X Font Service
font-service    7100/udp    xfs
http-alt    8080/tcp    webcache    # WWW caching service
http-alt    8080/udp            # WWW caching service
bacula-dir  9101/tcp            # Bacula Director
bacula-dir  9101/udp
bacula-fd   9102/tcp            # Bacula File Daemon
bacula-fd   9102/udp
bacula-sd   9103/tcp            # Bacula Storage Daemon
bacula-sd   9103/udp
xmms2       9667/tcp    # Cross-platform Music Multiplexing System
xmms2       9667/udp    # Cross-platform Music Multiplexing System
amanda      10080/tcp           # amanda backup services
amanda      10080/udp
hkp     11371/tcp           # OpenPGP HTTP Keyserver
hkp     11371/udp           # OpenPGP HTTP Keyserver
bprd        13720/tcp           # VERITAS NetBackup
bprd        13720/udp
bpdbm       13721/tcp           # VERITAS NetBackup
bpdbm       13721/udp
bpjava-msvc 13722/tcp           # BP Java MSVC Protocol
bpjava-msvc 13722/udp
vnetd       13724/tcp           # Veritas Network Utility
vnetd       13724/udp
bpcd        13782/tcp           # VERITAS NetBackup
bpcd        13782/udp
vopied      13783/tcp           # VERITAS NetBackup
vopied      13783/udp
wnn6        22273/tcp           # wnn6
wnn6        22273/udp

#
# Datagram Delivery Protocol services
#
rtmp        1/ddp           # Routing Table Maintenance Protocol
nbp     2/ddp           # Name Binding Protocol
echo        4/ddp           # AppleTalk Echo Protocol
zip     6/ddp           # Zone Information Protocol

#=========================================================================
# The remaining port numbers are not as allocated by IANA.
#=========================================================================

# Kerberos (Project Athena/MIT) services
# Note that these are for Kerberos v4, and are unofficial.  Sites running
# v4 should uncomment these and comment out the v5 entries above.
#
kerberos4   750/udp     kerberos-iv kdc # Kerberos (server)
kerberos4   750/tcp     kerberos-iv kdc
kerberos_master 751/udp             # Kerberos authentication
kerberos_master 751/tcp
passwd_server   752/udp             # Kerberos passwd server
krb_prop    754/tcp     krb5_prop hprop # Kerberos slave propagation
krbupdate   760/tcp     kreg        # Kerberos registration
swat        901/tcp             # swat
kpop        1109/tcp            # Pop with Kerberos
knetd       2053/tcp            # Kerberos de-multiplexor
zephyr-srv  2102/udp            # Zephyr server
zephyr-clt  2103/udp            # Zephyr serv-hm connection
zephyr-hm   2104/udp            # Zephyr hostmanager
eklogin     2105/tcp            # Kerberos encrypted rlogin
# Hmmm. Are we using Kv4 or Kv5 now? Worrying.
# The following is probably Kerberos v5  --- ajt@debian.org (11/02/2000)
kx      2111/tcp            # X over Kerberos
iprop       2121/tcp            # incremental propagation
#
# Unofficial but necessary (for NetBSD) services
#
supfilesrv  871/tcp             # SUP server
supfiledbg  1127/tcp            # SUP debugging

#
# Services added for the Debian GNU/Linux distribution
#
linuxconf   98/tcp              # LinuxConf
poppassd    106/tcp             # Eudora
poppassd    106/udp
ssmtp       465/tcp     smtps       # SMTP over SSL
moira_db    775/tcp             # Moira database
moira_update    777/tcp             # Moira update protocol
moira_ureg  779/udp             # Moira user registration
spamd       783/tcp             # spamassassin daemon
omirr       808/tcp     omirrd      # online mirror
omirr       808/udp     omirrd
customs     1001/tcp            # pmake customs server
customs     1001/udp
skkserv     1178/tcp            # skk jisho server port
predict     1210/udp            # predict -- satellite tracking
rmtcfg      1236/tcp            # Gracilis Packeten remote config server
wipld       1300/tcp            # Wipl network monitor
xtel        1313/tcp            # french minitel
xtelw       1314/tcp            # french minitel
support     1529/tcp            # GNATS
cfinger     2003/tcp            # GNU Finger
frox        2121/tcp            # frox: caching ftp proxy
ninstall    2150/tcp            # ninstall service
ninstall    2150/udp
zebrasrv    2600/tcp            # zebra service
zebra       2601/tcp            # zebra vty
ripd        2602/tcp            # ripd vty (zebra)
ripngd      2603/tcp            # ripngd vty (zebra)
ospfd       2604/tcp            # ospfd vty (zebra)
bgpd        2605/tcp            # bgpd vty (zebra)
ospf6d      2606/tcp            # ospf6d vty (zebra)
ospfapi     2607/tcp            # OSPF-API
isisd       2608/tcp            # ISISd vty (zebra)
afbackup    2988/tcp            # Afbackup system
afbackup    2988/udp
afmbackup   2989/tcp            # Afmbackup system
afmbackup   2989/udp
xtell       4224/tcp            # xtell server
fax     4557/tcp            # FAX transmission service (old)
hylafax     4559/tcp            # HylaFAX client-server protocol (new)
distmp3     4600/tcp            # distmp3host daemon
munin       4949/tcp    lrrd        # Munin
enbd-cstatd 5051/tcp            # ENBD client statd
enbd-sstatd 5052/tcp            # ENBD server statd
pcrd        5151/tcp            # PCR-1000 Daemon
noclog      5354/tcp            # noclogd with TCP (nocol)
noclog      5354/udp            # noclogd with UDP (nocol)
hostmon     5355/tcp            # hostmon uses TCP (nocol)
hostmon     5355/udp            # hostmon uses UDP (nocol)
rplay       5555/udp            # RPlay audio service
nsca        5667/tcp            # Nagios Agent - NSCA
mrtd        5674/tcp            # MRT Routing Daemon
bgpsim      5675/tcp            # MRT Routing Simulator
canna       5680/tcp            # cannaserver
sane-port   6566/tcp    sane saned  # SANE network scanner daemon
ircd        6667/tcp            # Internet Relay Chat
zope-ftp    8021/tcp            # zope management by ftp
tproxy      8081/tcp            # Transparent Proxy
omniorb     8088/tcp            # OmniORB
omniorb     8088/udp
clc-build-daemon 8990/tcp           # Common lisp build daemon
xinetd      9098/tcp
mandelspawn 9359/udp    mandelbrot  # network mandelbrot
git     9418/tcp            # Git Version Control System
zope        9673/tcp            # zope server
webmin      10000/tcp
kamanda     10081/tcp           # amanda backup services (Kerberos)
kamanda     10081/udp
amandaidx   10082/tcp           # amanda backup services
amidxtape   10083/tcp           # amanda backup services
smsqp       11201/tcp           # Alamin SMS gateway
smsqp       11201/udp
xpilot      15345/tcp           # XPilot Contact Port
xpilot      15345/udp
sgi-cmsd    17001/udp       # Cluster membership services daemon
sgi-crsd    17002/udp
sgi-gcd     17003/udp           # SGI Group membership daemon
sgi-cad     17004/tcp           # Cluster Admin daemon
isdnlog     20011/tcp           # isdn logging system
isdnlog     20011/udp
vboxd       20012/tcp           # voice box system
vboxd       20012/udp
binkp       24554/tcp           # binkp fidonet protocol
asp     27374/tcp           # Address Search Protocol
asp     27374/udp
csync2      30865/tcp           # cluster synchronization tool
dircproxy   57000/tcp           # Detachable IRC Proxy
tfido       60177/tcp           # fidonet EMSI over telnet
fido        60179/tcp           # fidonet EMSI over TCP

# Local services
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to reboot my machine until I had replaced this file. :S

Comment: No, that's understandable. I've added a method showing how to find where a file comes from, and how to get a brand new, straight-from-the-package fresh copy of the file.

Comment: `/etc/services` is rarely modified (and not by any package, I think). It's mostly a repository of de jure or de facto name to port assignments for UDP and TCP services.

Comment: @Gilles My desktop version was modified by the `pipslite` installer to add `cbtd     35587/tcp`... I thought that's why there's a `# Local services` section at the bottom.

Comment: I'm always adding stuff into /etc/services as xinetd requires it too.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12699/how-can-i-revert-a-config-file-back-to-the-originally-installed-version-after-i-h) should be able to help you out on how to get the file back and how to back up your `/etc` directory.

Comment: Which package would /etc/services be under..?

Comment: @tommed: You can find out by running `dpkg -S /etc/services`. Another way, if you've installed the `dlocate` package, is `dlocate /etc/services` (it's a little faster because it relies on a daily-regenerated index).

Answer (score -2):

You can simply run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure netbase
```

This might not work, e.g. if you have cleaned out your downloaded packages but it's worth a try. It worked for me

Comment: That might not be sufficient to restore the file.