# How I can synchronise my configuration files and store the backup on another HDD?

Tags: backup, etc

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 and daily I am making some changes to configuration files in `/etc`.

I want to synchronize these files daily and take a backup of them stored on another partition? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is an overkill solution but you can use [etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/), and similar question is well answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279140/is-there-an-application-to-manage-config-files-in-the-etc-directory-with-versio).

In short:

1. `sudo apt install etckeeper`
2. Choose any git **private** repository ([bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) if you want easy way, or your local git repo/folder on your own server)
3. Add the repository as `origin` to the etckeeper `cd /etc; git remote add origin <some-git-repo>`
4. Uncomment/add `"PUSH_REMOTE="origin"` in `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf`
5. Make the initial commit `cd /etc; git push -u origin master`

And you are done. etckeeper has daily cronjob (`/etc/cron.daily/etckeeper`) that will do the trick as also a trigger (`cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05etckeeper`) to apt-commands(apt-get, apt, aptitude)  which will update on each package change. You can also invoke the commit manually by running `etckeeper commit`

---

If you want simpler solution - add a daily cron job:

```
cat >/etc/cron.daily/my_backup <<'EOF'
tar czf /your/backup/dir "etc_$(date +%F_%T|sed -e 's/:/-/g')" /etc
EOF
```

---

I personally suggest you not to backup on another partition on the same physical unless this is really separate SSD/HDD bought at different time/manufacturer from the one containing your /etc/ folder.

The best backup is somewhere apart form your main source of valuable information... Think of a simple fire scenarios for example.