# Is there a general way to reset a package's per-user config files?

Tags: unity

I recently had a problem with Unity where it wasn't starting for a particular user. This led me to wanting to reset the Unity config files to their "out of the box" versions, to eliminate the possibility that a config setting was causing problems.

After finding a method and fixing the problem, it led to me wonder if there is a general way to reset a package's configuration files for a given user, rather than searching the ~/.config directory and removing appropriate looking files?

I'm looking specifically for a way of resetting the user's local config, rather than a global config in, say, /etc

Comment: That looks to deal with a way of resetting the global config. While that's useful to know, I was looking for a way to reset the user's local config.

Comment: You'd remove config files by searching. Packages do not control per user config files

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/why-do-some-applications-use-config-appname-for-their-config-data-while-other

Comment: As you edited your question, I retracted my close vote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I revert a config file back to the originally installed version after I have edited it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12699/how-can-i-revert-a-config-file-back-to-the-originally-installed-version-after-i)

Comment: That looks to deal with a way of resetting the global config. While that's useful to know, I was looking for a way to reset the user's local config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic way to revert user-config for a package. Each package can store their own user config in user's home directory. Usually where these are stored are described in manual pages of a package, but not always.

You have to find and remove those files manually. Most of the configs for GTK applications are found in `~/.config` directory

You might want to read this useful question on Unix & Linux SE about config files folder.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/why-do-some-applications-use-config-appname-for-their-config-data-while-other

(Thanks to edwinksl for the link)