# Can you paste the original Ubuntu 20.04 syslog.service file content for me?

Tags: 20.04, services, restore, syslog, paste

While adding a new service to the `/etc/systemd/system/` folder, I have accidentally edited the `syslog.service` file and lost its original content.

Can someone paste the original file content here for me?

Or does anybody know how to restore it? I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/817725/1599303), but I don't know which package I should reinstall, and can't find it by file on https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Side note: if you have the installation ISO, you can mount the system partition from that somewhere, and that should include said file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My system is a 20.04.4 server. I do not know if desktop is the same:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/syslog.service
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service
Requires=syslog.socket
Documentation=man:rsyslogd(8)
Documentation=https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

# Increase the default a bit in order to allow many simultaneous
# files to be monitored, we might need a lot of fds.
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=syslog.service
```

Comment: exactly the same here with 20.04 LTS